# Can't book company reserved seats for spouse

Tags: bookings, family

OK so this is a bit funny.
I'm trying to book a ticket for me through company website, and for wife through public airline website, same flight number, date and time. It's a long flight.

On public website the seats that are available in company website look blocked and vice-versa. All economy.

This looks silly, there's plenty seats available but I can't book together and the phone attendant said there's nothing they can do.

Any way around it? Assuming I must book mine through company website.

Comment: What website? What company? What airline? It's really going to have to be a question for your company travel controller, we can't control or know your company policies, systems or rules :(

Comment: It looks like you have 3 options: Get your company to approve booking your wife in company-booked seating, book both of your seats from the public seating (possibly with company reimbursement), or book separate seats and hope you find someone nice to swap with when you get on the plane (for instance: book next to a friend, and agree that after takeoff your friend and wife will swap places).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are booking into a trip that many members of your company are going on, perhaps meetings or conference or company gathering?  If this is the case, then perhaps your company has booked a block of tickets and seats for the group and you are only booking/buying one of those seats for your self.

Once you have your tickets purchased for both you and your wife, you could try calling the airline to see if they can move your seat out of the company block and into the general seating area next to your wife.

But if your booking is tied to the block, then they might not be able to move you.  In this case what you might try doing is picking two reasonable seats in the area outside your block, say an aisle and a middle, put your wife's seat in the middle and then choose a similar aisle seat for your self at the back or front of your company block.  That way is the airline is totally unable to change your seat before the flight, you can always ask the person in the aisle seat next to your wife to swap for your aisle seat.